# What is the best way to model multi-part questions

Tags: class, design-patterns, object, properties, class-design

I am trying to design a subclass that will contain responses to multipart questions and some logic to evaluate/act on them.  For example, FoodSurvey would be a subclass of BaseSurvey

```
BaseSurvey
  Name
  Date
  Submit()

FoodSurvey <- BaseSurvey
  DoYouLikeIcecream
  IfSoWhatFlavour
  WouldYouLikeAFreeSample
  SendSample(flavour)
  ...
```

FoodSurvey could have several dozen or more questions, and I would need to valdate each answer based on others, as well as run some other processes specific to FoodSurvey (as opposed to CarSurvey) that may depend on multiple answers (ex: SendSample(rockyRoad)).

I have toyed with the idea of a Question class with a Questions collection in each Survey but this quickly started to look like a Survey 'engine' which seemed like it 1.) was overkill, 2.) was error prone and 3.) limited the logic I could use to validate answers.

Are there any accepted best practices regarding designing this type of class?

If it matters, the classes will eventually be used in an ASP.NET website or web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your approach of having a 'Question' class. In more detail, this model could use a type/object patter - sort of like the relationship between a type and an object. The code could look like this:

```
class Question
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

class QuestionAnswer
{
    public Question Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}

interface ISurveyValidator
{
    bool Validate(SurveyType type, IEnumerable<QuestionAnswer> answers);
}

class SurveyType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Question> Questions { get; set; }

    public ISurveyValidator Validator { get; set; }

    public Survey CreateSurvey(IEnumerable<QuestionAnswer> answers)
    {
        if (!this.Validator.Validate(this, answers))
            throw new Exception();
        return new Survey
        {
            Type = this,
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            Answers = answers.ToList()
        };
    }
}

class Survey
{
    public SurveyType Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public IList<QuestionAnswer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

This would allow you to provide custom validation for each survey type.

Comment: Thanks @eulerfx.  This is very close to what I've already played with.  I'm fond of the Question class b/c I can add Prompt, HelpText, ControlType properties to auotmate the UI building later.  One thing I'm stuck on is how to allow varible Answer types in the QuestionAnswer (ex: boolean, string, integer, etc.)  This was not an issue when each question was a seperate property.  Any ideas?

Comment: There are many ways you can enforce a 'type' and answers. One simple way would be to associate a QuestionType enum with each question, then the validator can confirm that the answer satisfies the type. This would allow answers to remain strings, since strings can contain any type of data and can be easily bound. Another option is to associate a validating Regex with each question. Yet another option would be to subtype the answer class to support specific types.

Comment: I also thought of storing everything as strings as this mimics the natural act of filling a form.  Could you give an example of how the subtype method would be used, say for integer answers?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're being too hard on yourself when you say 'overkill'. Thinking about scalability and modularity from the start is good design practice in my books, regardless of project size.

I like the idea of a Question class. You could potentially have a member array of Pattern/RegEx objects (whatever they're called in ASP.NET) and a method that takes a String answer, and walks the array trying to match it. You could include final members for point value, topic, hint, etc. Sounds like a perfect candidate for its own class.
In terms of 'linking questions' based on the response to a previous question, perhaps this could be done as simply as  maintaining a list of answers » next_question pairings, with a default case for those that 'don't like ice cream". This might be a good use case for a hash table, or even an array of objects of a new class - NextQuestionPair, which includes members for 'answer selected' and 'next question'.

EDIT: Think trees, choosing branches based on answers (or lack thereof)

Comment: Thanks AlexWebr.  +1 for advocating scalability and modularity.  I also like your idea about the next question pairings.